# How to store an unsigned int in an array of structs?

Tags: c

I'm doing a project for school and got a problem where I haven't been able to store data to an unsigned int that is in an array of a struct. I get no errors when running it off of the console (./project) and the result shows up all right.
But when running it with valgrind I get a "Invalid write" error when trying to write the unsigned value and an "Invalid Read" when trying to read it.

Here's a simplified version of the code that has the same problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct prueba{
  int num;
  char letra;
  unsigned int nam;
};
typedef struct prueba prueba;

int main(){
  prueba * array[10];
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    array[i]=malloc(sizeof(prueba *));
  }
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    array[i]->num=i;
    array[i]->letra='P';
    array[i]->nam=i*i;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("%d ", array[i]->num);
    printf("%c ", array[i]->letra);
    printf("%u", array[i]->nam);
    printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
      free(array[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are mallocing with `sizeof(prueba *)` instead of `sizeof(prueba)`

Comment: Thanks that worked! But why tho? I'm new to C and haven't been able to get a grasp over malloc

Comment: It is an array of pointers, but they point to a `struct`, so that much memory needs to be allocated for each (not the size of the pointer). BTW it is a well-presented question.

Comment: Thanks very much, both for the answer and the compliment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[i]=malloc(sizeof(prueba *));`

is incorrect. It must be

`array[i]=malloc(sizeof(prueba));`

The first one reserves memory that is big enough so that a pointer to a prueba struct can fit inside but what you want is memory big enough so that an entire prueba struct fits inside.

But you can save yourself all of this by replacing

`prueba * array[10];`

with

`prueba array[10];`

Why storing ten pointers to structures in an array and storing the structures in external memory, when you can as well store ten structures in an array? Instead of using `array[x]->y` you can now access the values using `array[x].y`.

If you don't want to do it on the stack, you could also do:

`prueba * array = calloc(10, sizeof(prueba));`

Now you also created an array that directly contains 10 structs, just not on stack but on heap and in the end you free all of them with

`free(array);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it is correct. And as you said, I would have very much prefered to use an array; thing is that the rules of the assignment prohibit it's use. The idea being getting students to familiarize themselves with the of use of pointer and allocation of memory. Thanks again!

Comment: Code could avoid the wrong size by not coding the type at all.  `array[i]=malloc(sizeof(prueba *));` --> `array[i] = malloc(sizeof *(array[i]));`.